# Add Cancel URL - Mollie Payment

Tags: php, laravel, mollie

I have implemented [Mollie Payment](https://github.com/mollie/laravel-mollie) with my Laravel framework.

How to add cancel URL to redirect to cancel screen? As I have checked in the documentation, it is having only redirection URL. I haven't find anything yet for this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.
Include the relevant code snippets you have tried so far.

Comment: Hello @mayuri, Did you get any solution. I'm also trying to achieve the same thing in laravel.

Answer (score 0):

reading the [documentation](https://docs.mollie.com/reference/v2/payments-api/cancel-payment) , what I would do, is something similar:

```
$canceled_payment = $mollie->payments->delete($payment_id);
return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Payment cancelled');
```

And into blade, you should show the message:

```
@if(session()->has('message'))
<div class="alert alert-success">
    {{ session()->get('message') }}
</div>
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks, But i don't find any solution for cancel URL button from where i need to redirect page. My  question is how set cancel URL from Mollie payment page??

Comment: You should create a function that check if user has requested to cancel the payment.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to specify the 'cancelled' Url with Mollie. And there will never be. See a [comment from Mollie's team member on Github](https://github.com/mollie/mollie-api-php/issues/18#issuecomment-255081190):

> Hey guys, just wanted to chime in to see what we can do at Mollie to clear things up.
>
> As stated earlier, we use a webhook system to send you status updates about your payments. We explicitly do NOT support a cancelUrl or any other type of status dependent URL, because it introduces various security issues that our webhook system has solved.
>
> (...)
>
> In short: **we will never implement a cancelUrl because it goes entirely against our API design**. Please feel free to ask us more about our webhook system if you still have questions.

However:

> Just set up your payment with a webhook URL where we can push the status to. Send your consumer off to the gateway URL we provide. Then we will send your consumer back to the redirect URL you've provided once they either cancel or complete the payment. In both events, **we will generally have called your webhook URL right before the consumer returns to your website**, allowing you to show a proper status message to your consumers.

So what you can do, is to specify the order id in the redirectUrl (possibly inside a [JWT](https://jwt.io/) for extra security). You should send that order id  to Mollie in [payment metadata](https://docs.mollie.com/payments/overview#using-metadata). Then, in your webhook's controller you should store the Mollie payment status, linked to your order (when the user cancells the transaction by clicking "Back to the website" link, this status is `canceled`). Finally, once Mollie redirects the user to your `redirectUrl`, you check (in your controller) the payment status of the order. If it is `canceled`, show the cancelled view. Otherwise, show the success screen.